# how to get difference of sums of 2 different type of transactions in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
table - id, user_id, amount, type int(1), timestamp.
```

type 1- debit
0- credit

I want to get the current balance of a user, i.e. sum of all credits - sum of all debits

can anyone help me on this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If credits are positive and debits are negative, then just do this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount), 0)
FROM t
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

If they are both positive, you could do this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN -amount ELSE amount END)
FROM t
WHERE user_id = 1
```

(Assuming that type = 1 is a credit and type = 2 is a debit.)

If you want it for *all* users, just change the `WHERE` clause to `GROUP BY user_id`.

**EDIT**: To answer your question about no entries for a given user: probably it *should* return `NULL` if you ask for a user who isn't in the table (e.g. as part of a left join?), but if you really want zero you can say `COALESCE(SUM(...), 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. It is returning NULL if there is no entry for any particular user. How to make it return 0.00 in case of no entry for a user?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT user_id, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalDebit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalCredit
  FROM table
 GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: I looks like this counts how many times the user had a credit or debit, but I believe the question is asking how to compute the current balance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query

```
SELECT user_id, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN type = '1' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) totalDebit,
   SUM(CASE WHEN type = '0' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) totalCredit
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```